# Is there a Stack Exchange site for questions relating to morals?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I had this one question that I posted on Philosophy Stack Exchange as I could not find a better and more related site suited for the question. But, it was not very well received and I was recommended to move this question. I looked the Stack Exchange sites archive up again, but could still not find a more related site. So here I am, looking for suggestions.

Link to my question : https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/41726/a-dilemma-a-person-who-cant-teach-properly-is-passionate-about-teaching-sh

The question I linked deals with the dilemma of a student, who is studying under a passionate teacher. Main problem is that the teacher is not a good teacher and cannot teach properly.

Comment: Maybe [academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but check their meta first **before** you post.

Comment: Teaching is a skill; it must be learnt. The teacher is new to the field. Maybe your fellow students  and you can help him become a better teacher. If you can find an appropriate way to give him feedback.

Answer (score 7):

As with rene's comment, my thought also goes with [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/), *except* I still don't feel your question as it stands will be well-received there, mainly due to the fundamental question:

> Should an ideal student respect him? And study under him when he can possibly study under a far better teacher?

This is heavily, heavily opinion based and non-specific, and as such may not find a happy home on *any* of the SE sites, possibly being more appropriate for another forum elsewhere.

*That said*, you may be able to get this question to fly *if* you can reframe it in a way that focuses on *your* feelings towards the teacher and a *concrete, specific* problem and choice you have to make, and the direct consequences of that choice as it relates to your future. (Note I am assuming you are the student in this case; but if you are the teacher, similar advice holds.)

However, the other issue is that Academia specifically focuses on university-level topics, and if this is e.g. a pre-university question, it is [unlikely to be on topic there](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1170/12142).

**And that advice comes with this heavy disclaimer:** I am not active on Academia. I do not know what is or is not generally acceptable there. You most certainly want to do one or more of the following first (this is the general set of advice I give for *any* site):

- Read https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.
- Read https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask, noting specifically:

  > You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
  >
  > Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.
- Scan through the rest of https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/asking
- Browse through the top questions in various tags (e.g. [ethics](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethics?sort=votes)) for examples of what is acceptable.
- Ask in https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2496/the-ivory-tower
- Ask on https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/

I cannot think of any other options, so if this does not work for Academia, you may be out of luck here.

Comment: This was a very helpful piece of advice and a very well written and detailed answer. I am currently waiting for any reply from community on the chat room Ivory Tower regarding my issue that you and @rene already raised there. In case it goes unnoticed I shall try Academia meta.

Comment: The Academia SE is for topics relevant to graduate students, researchers, and university educators.  We'll see what the site thinks now that it's already been moved there, but I don't think this question raises to that level, personally.  Possibly the Math Educators SE would be a fit, though I find their help pages on what constitutes "On Topic" to be rather ambiguous here.  It mentions that questions about "learning mathematics" are on-topic, but that sounds more like a "theory of learning and how to use it as an educator" type of thing, not a student concerns thing.